# reproducir sonido luego recargar

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo este codigo:

```
var audio = new Audio('archivos/notificacion2.mp3');
audio.preload = 'auto';
audio.volume = .9;
delay = 1;
if(/^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {delay = 0;}
```

sirve para reproducir notificacion2.mp3 si llamo a audio.play();
pero yo estoy haciendo esto:

```
audio.play();
setTimeout(
  ()=>{
    location.reload()
  },1000
  )
```

lo que quiero es que primero suene y luego se recargue e intentado con el codigo anterior pero solo se recarga y no suena nada, e intentado mediante consola llamar a audio.play() y si suena

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente se debe espera a que el audio termine para hacer algo.

Segundo, es díficil usar `setTimeout` para hacer algo, ya que con éste hay que saber cuántos minutos o segundos dura el audio, y calcular que haga algo al terminar el audio.

Lo más fácil de hacer algo es usando el evento `ended` del audio para luego hacer algo:

```
audio.addEventListener("ended", () => {
    
    location.reload()
    
});
```

Con jQuery sería lo siguiente:

```
$(audio).on("ended", function() {

    location.reload()
});
```